# Why getting cookie back for HttpHead method?

Tags: java, cookies, warnings, httpclient

We are using HttpHead to get the info from our customer's website, but for some reason we are getting cookie in the response as well. Is it expected? Is there a way to set to not return cookie?

The following is the code we have

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // the time it takes to open TCP connection.
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, this.timeout);

        // timeout when server does not send data.
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, this.timeout);

        // the head method
        HttpHead httphead = new HttpHead(url);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httphead);
```

And we are getting the following warning, indicating that there was cookie returned with response as well.

[WARN] ResponseProcessCookies - Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: DXFXFSG][value: AUR][domain: ...omitted...][path: /][expiry: null]". Illegal domain attribute "...omitted...". Domain of origin: "...omitted..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is expected; you should get the same response as for the equivalent `GET` except that there is no body.  If the `GET` would include a cookie, you should see it.

As an aside, I believe the warning you are seeing, from the redacted message you gave, is that the server is trying to set a cookie for a different domain.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I think your observation is correct. And sounds like there is no way to stop server side from returning cookies.